# Connecting MVC++ with SQLAPI++

Tags: mysql, visual-c++

I am using Microsoft Visual c++ 2008 Express Edition.

I followed the SQL API website [http://www.sqlapi.com/index.html].

I have Installed SqlApi++, but but my Compiler is not detecting `#include <SQLAPI.h>`

What am I doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>  // for printf
#include <SQLAPI.h> // main SQLAPI++ header

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SAConnection con; // create connection object

    try
    {
        // connect to database
        // in this example it is Oracle,
        // but can also be Sybase, Informix, DB2
        // SQLServer, InterBase, SQLBase and ODBC
        con.Connect(
            "test",     // database name
            "tester",   // user name
            "tester",   // password
            SA_Oracle_Client);

        printf("We are connected!\n");

        // Disconnect is optional
        // autodisconnect will ocur in destructor if needed
        con.Disconnect();

        printf("We are disconnected!\n");
    }
    catch(SAException &x)
    {
        // SAConnection::Rollback()
        // can also throw an exception
        // (if a network error for example),
        // we will be ready
        try
        {
            // on error rollback changes
            con.Rollback();
        }
        catch(SAException &)
        {
        }
        // print error message
        printf("%s\n", (const char*)x.ErrText());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, check if you added the include directory with SQLAPI headers file into the list of additional include directories for your project (open project's property pages, select tab C++\General, chnage property "Additional include directories" to add the **include** subdirectory of SQLAPI++ distribution.

probably, you have to do the same for SQLAPI libraries (add the path to **lib** folder  into property "Additional library directories" of tab "Linker/General")

Comment: @Seril I am doing that..and my point is that.now i need to open my sqlApI to check Databases and Tables present.i am not able to see anywhere under program files.I just want to do exactly like what we do in sqlserver 2005. i hope sqlApi should provide this options

Comment: @seril I have made the changes.Now compiler is able to detect header files.Now this con.Connect(
            "test",     // database name
            "tester",   // user name
            "tester",   // password
            SA_Oracle_Client);
has problem..i suppose i need to open my sqlapi then create new database then i think it will work.can you just guide me how it will i do this?